# How to convert Date timestamp format to Date Month in Status History Dashboard in Grafana?

Tags: visualization, grafana, dashboard

I am trying to display the dates like in the image from format MM/DD like 06/01 to 01 June and likewise for other dates for Interpretability.

[image]

I tried using transform as well as Override ways but nothing works in this case. Can you share your idea about this ?

Comment: I believe date format is a [server wide config](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.2/administration/configuration/#date_formats).

Comment: Is it possible to do it from Rename by Regex ? Or Transform ? Value Mapping ? Override ?

Comment: I don't think so. Listed are operations over time series visualized by panel, not panel itself. IIRC,  the was a possibility to make date format dependant on user browser timezone/time format.